# Get table name which do not have a particular column

Tags: oracle

I have to list the table names (in oracle) that do NOT have a particular column or columns.
Any suggestions?

Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table_name from all_tables 
minus 
select table_name from all_tab_cols where column_name = 'YOUR_COL';
```

Comment: Change this to the USER_ views and it should be just about right.

Comment: When selecting from ALL_ views it's a good idea to include OWNER, to avoid different tables of the same name in multiple schemas muddying the results. .

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to expedite my task. Sorry for delayed response.

Comment: You're welcome. I've used all_ not user_ because in question it is not mentioned one want only user tables or all tables. But if you need only yours tables as mentioned in comment please use user_tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try;

```
SELECT ut.table_name
FROM   user_tables ut
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
           FROM   user_tab_columns utc
           WHERE      utc.table_name = ut.table_name
                  AND utc.column_name = 'your_column')
```

Which will check just in the schema you are currently using.
You can change it to the ALL_ views but then you will most likely need to filter out schema owners like 'SYS', SYSTEM, 'MDSYS', etc.
The answer by @Kacper will likely be suitable for you most of the time. This one has the potential to be quicker as it could use indexes in theory but I haven't checked and it probably depends on what you want to limit the query by.